# Polylang and bulk Products translation in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation, product, polylang

I have a woocommerce website with more than 1500 products. Now we have bought Polylang Pro for Woocommerce in order to add a new language on the website.
My question is, how can I translate all products in one shot? 
The only way that I can see is to translate one product at time...but there are too many products... Do you know how can we do this?

Thanks

Comment: You should better ask Polylang Pro support, as your question doesn't involve directly programing and StackOverFlow don't handle any software support.

Comment: Thanks! I'll ask to support of Polylang.